# Bloomberg API: Can I use TLS with Python SDK?

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

I am trying to connect to Bloomberg ZFP Service using TLS trust material and credentials. I could find how to do it with C++ and with Java, But is it possible to achieve using [BLPAPI Python SDK](https://github.com/msitt/blpapi-python)?

For example, this is how it looks when I login with cpp examples:

```
./ConnectionAndAuthExample_64\
    -host api.xx.net \
    -auth "app=xxx" \
    -tls-client-credentials /home/xx.pk12 \
    -tls-client-credentials-password xxx \
    -tls-trust-material /home/xxx.pk7

ConnectionAndAuthExample
TlsOptions enabled
api.xxx.net:8194

TokenGenerationSuccess = {
    token = "-v4;3/xxxx/h+xxxxxxxxx/xxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx;xxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx++xxxxx+//xxxxxxxxxxxxx+xxxxxxxxxxx;"
}
...
```

If not possible, can I generate auth token with a simple C++ script and re-use it with a session created with Python SDK?, in that case how should I create the session object?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The current Python SDK does not support connecting to ZFP. Your available choices are C++, Java and DotNet (C# and VB.Net)

You can generate authentications in C++ (or any other language in the SDK) and use it in authorization request in another language. The token you are referring to here is for authenticating and authorizing B-Pipe Users and Application and not for securing connection to ZFP, the latter requires certs and password.